# Drawables pulled from wrong resource folder on rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-activity, android-resources, android-drawable

Pulling my hair out here. So I'm working with an application that has several types of drawables, and I have them in a structure like so:

```
res/
    //Portrait resources
    drawable-mdpi/
    drawable-hdpi/
    drawable-xhdpi/

    //Landscape resources
    drawable-land-mdpi/
    drawable-land-hdpi/
    drawable-land-xhdpi/
```

**EDIT** I've also tried even putting the portrait-specific drawables under `drawable-port-mdpi`, etc. with the same result.

And I have a custom `View` which I'm using to pull in drawables at runtime. Here's a pared-down example, but this is where I'm having an issue:

```
public class CustomView extends FrameLayout {
    private ImageView mBackgroundView;

    public CustomView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public CustomView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public CustomView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize () {
        mBackgroundView = new ImageView(getContext());
        mBackgroundView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_resource);
        addView(mBackgroundView, wrapContent());
    }

    private LayoutParams wrapContent () {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

I would expect that when I rotate to landscape (and let me first clarify, I **AM NOT** handling `configChanges` in the manifest for this `Activity`) and this `View` is re-created, `mBackgroundView` should get the drawable in `drawable-land-xhdpi`. Conversely when I rotate back, I should get the drawable in `drawable-xhdpi`.

Now here's where it gets weird. I can confirm that the drawables are all there and detected, as **if I launch the app in landscape, I get the correct landscape drawable**. However, on rotation, the landscape drawable remains, and I do not get the portrait one. Conversely, **if I launch in portrait, I'm stuck with the portrait drawable.**

Is there some special case that I'm supposed to handle to "reset" the resources or something when I'm grabbing them programmatically?

Comment: What version of Android? Do you have screen auto-rotation enabled?

Comment: @cdonner Yes, the screen rotates, and I get the layout defined in `layout-land`. It's just the drawable that doesn't change. Also, this is on Android 4.2 (Nexus 4 and Galaxy Nexus both show this problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured out where the problem resides, and I'm honestly not sure if it's my misunderstanding or a bug in Android. I didn't think to add this as part of the question (looking back, I should have) but my drawable was a layer-list drawable with two images stacked atop each other (one shadow, one image above the shadow) :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/shadow"/>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image" android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It seems that this only gets parsed out *once* (I'm assuming for efficiency it's reused) but it never goes back and reconstructs the layer-list with the drawables for the new configuration.

I changed to using two aligned ImageViews instead of a layer-list drawable and all is well.

Comment: I just found i have the same problem, i was using this in a style for all activities, with a shape for background color and a bitmap, but it seems depending of the position it starts it will not adapt to rotations. Can you show your xml with imageviews? can this be used in a style theme?